# Error Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo in Sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I have a SQL Server database file `Database1.mdf`. Every time I want to add a New Component (does not matter if it's a table, a function or something else), I get this error

> The File or Assenbly "Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8845dcd8080cc91" or one of its dependencies not found. The system can not find the file specified.

I did install the `SQLSysClrTypes.msi` and the `SharedManagmentObjects.msi`.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate (Trial)

Comment: Do you have a reference to the dll in your project? You can try removing that reference and adding it again.

Comment: What ms sql server version?

Comment: @codemonkey No i dont have any references in the project ( It a fresh one)

Comment: @Maciej Los: I think its SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay

I had to run the installer of Visual studio again, then it worked!

Answer (score 4):

Symptoms:

You receive the following error:

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo[...]

Cause:

You have not installed the SQL Shared Management Objects (SMO). They are needed to create tables and other SQL objects from TX.

Resolution:

Download the SQL Shared Management Objects from the SQL Server Feature Packages and install it. The download sites are linked below - the file you need is called SharedManagementObjects.msi.

1. [SQL Server 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35580)
2. [SQL Server 2008 R2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30440)
3. [SQL Server 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6375)
4. [SQL Server 2005](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11988)

Please be aware that if you are using another version of SQL server, you must find the right version of the feature packages.

Notes:
If you are deploying to multiple versions of SQL Server, you must install all the relevant versions of SMO/XMO. For example, if staging is SQL 2008 and Data Warehouse is SQL 2012, you must install both of these files.

SQL Native Client is a pre-requisite and will in most cases need to be installed first.
In some cases, you wil also need to install the Analysys Management Objects package to resolve this error.

Comment: i did like you said, now i cant even create a new database file !

Comment: may be its related with your VS version.

Comment: Nah fixed it by reinstalling visual studio

Comment: Links are dead, 404...

Answer (score 1):

I face this problem too. The problem was fixed by replace the same version of Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll in application and database. So Please make sure that you are using sql sever 2014(Version 12.0.0.0) and Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll version 12.0.0.0 too.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:** This issue happens when assembly `Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo, Version=12.0.0.0` not found by visual studio. The problem was **Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio** was not installed yet.

**Solution:**  for Visual Studio 2013 just go to http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784 and download:

- `vcredist_x64.exe` for X64 OS or
- `vcredist_x86.exe` for X86 OS,

then install it, and restart visual studio.

---

PS: You can find *Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 20XX* for other versions of Visual Studio easily by googling it.

Comment: Looking here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145, it makes no mention of SQL server components. I don't think installaing that package will install SQL server components.