# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, smo

I am facing this issue

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

I am using SQL Server 2019 and SSMS 18 I checked my folder where SDK and assemblies exist there is not Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo DLL in 130 , 150 SDK folder of SQL server.

how can I solve it, is it SMO problem or other
Thanks

Comment: Hi Dale, and welcome. Could you take a look at this post and see if any of the resolutions are applicable to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27650672/error-microsoft-sqlserver-connectioninfo-in-sql